# Where can I find an example of a file workflow.rst for generating snakemake reports?

Tags: reporting, snakemake

I am trying to use the reporting function of snakemake which is documented here:
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/reporting.html

However I am finding it hard to find a meaningful example of what the workflow.rst file should look like.

I have looked at the output example
https://koesterlab.github.io/resources/report.html

but I can't find the code to generate this report.

Comment: The link in the documentation (https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/src/master/tests/test_report/) seems to be broken. You should probably submit an issue at https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the link in the documentation is broken.

I found an example in the tests of snakemake:

https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/tree/master/tests/test_report

The snakefile generating a report is there:
https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/master/tests/test_report/Snakefile

It uses the following .rst file:
https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/master/tests/test_report/report/workflow.rst